# Adobe Illustrator PNG export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png, resolution, scale

I have to export my illustration as the best resolution. Adobe Illustrator allows me to export as a PNG with only 4x scale, is there any option to unlock this for higher scales? Or can you recommend any programs, which are able to export ai/eps/pdf files without limits?

(specs: GTX 1070, i7 6700k, 32GB of RAM, Win10)

Thanks!

[image: even 8x is too much]

Comment: You could use *File > Export > Save for Web (Legacy)* to get full control of the output size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to export my illustration as the best resolution

The best resolution is not a humungous overexaggerated resolution.

The best resolution is the one you need for the project.

So, the best resolution for a website could be 500px, or for a banner could be 6000px.

But if you want a humungous resolution to be printed at a really big format, leave the image as vectors. That is what vectors are for, they are resolution-free.

---

> Or can you recommend any programs, which are able to export ai/eps/pdf files without limits?

I believe, "without limits" is limited to the physical properties of the known universe. So, not even a quantum computer or all the computer power of the humanity can.

---

File size is limited by either the file format, or the operating system, or the physical capability of the computer.

For example, a bitmap image could be "only" about 32,000 x 32,000 px.

On Windows, it could be for example 2 or 4Gb